# Tomcat not publishing latest changes

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am currently working on a Java application in Eclipse and I am using Tomcat as a server. I noticed that when I make changes on the files and publish,  the application does not take into account the changes (The deployed application in the Tomcat folder is still consisted of the old files). I have tried:

1. Restarting the server
2. Cleaning the server
3. Cleaning the project
4. Creating a new server and uploading there
5. Setting on and off the automatic publish of the Server

And nothing has worked. 
The only thing that makes the server upload the latest version is to remove the app from the server, build it with maven and deploy it again.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

> EDIT: I installed new Tomcat and Eclipse Oxygen. Publishing still doesn`t update the uploaded application

Comment: which version of eclipse are you using? which version of tomcat?

Comment: Hi
I am using eclipse Neon and Tomcat 8

Comment: Click on the Tomcat Server in your Server's tab. On the right hand side under Publishing, select "Automatically publish when resources change". RESTART. See if it helps.

Comment: Hi hiren
I have already tried that.